# Find potential function of a vector field

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

We have $\vec{F}(x,y,z) = (2xcos(y)-2z^3)i + (3+2ye^z-x^2sin(y)) j + (y^2e^z-6xz^2) k$

Now a potential field $\vec{F}(x,y,z) = grad(\phi)(x,y,z) = f_x(x,y,z)i+f_y(x,y,z)j+f_z(x,y,z)k$

But after taking the partials $\vec{F}(x,y,z) \neq grad(\phi)(x,y,z)$

Since $f_x(x,y,z)i$ = $2cos(y)-2z^3$ $f_y(x,y,z)j = 3+2e^z-x^2 sin(y)$ and $f_x(x,y,z)k = y^2e^z-6x2z$ which is not equal to our original $\vec{F}(x,y,z)$

So $\phi(x,y,z) = 2cos(y)-2z^3 + 3+2e^z-x^2 sin(y) + y^2e^z-6x2z \neq \vec{F}(x,y,z)$ $ = (2xcos(y)-2z^3)i + (3+2ye^z-x^2sin(y))j + (y^2e^z-6xz^2)k$

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti $\phi(x,y,z) = 2cos(y)-2z^3 + 3+2e^z-x^2 sin(y) + y^2e^z-6x2z$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\vec{F}(x,y,z) = (2x \cos y - 2z^3) \hat i + (3+2ye^z-x^2 \sin y) \hat j + (y^2e^z-6xz^2) \hat k$

Checking, the curl of the vector field is $(0, 0, 0)$ so it is a conservative vector field. To find potential function, we first integrate $\hat i$ component of the vector field with respect to $dx$.

$f(x, y, z) = x^2 \cos y - 2 x z^3 + \int g(y, z) \ dy$

Taking $\hat j$ component, $g(y, z) = 3 + 2 y e^z$

Now integrating $g(y, z)$ with respect to $dy$,

$f(x, y, z) = x^2 \cos y - 2 x z^3 + 3 y + y^2 e^z + \int h(z) \ dz$

Checking $\hat k$ component, $h(z) = 0$

So $f(x, y, z) = x^2 \cos y - 2 x z^3 + 3 y + y^2 e^z$

Comment: Is this just the first part of the solution? I note that So $f(x, y, z) = x^2 \cos y - 2 x z^3 + 3 y + y^2 e^z = \neq$ the i term in our original function...

Comment: $f(x, y, z)$ is the potential function. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ gives you $i$ component.

Comment: why is $h(z) = 0$ ?

Comment: $k$ component is $(y^2e^z-6xz^2)$, there is no part in here that is only a function of $z$.

Comment: Another way to look at it, $f(x, y, z) = x^2 \cos y - 2 x z^3 + 3 y + y^2 e^z + \int h(z) \ dz$. Take partial derivative wrt $z$ and you get $y^2e^z - 6xz^2 + h(z)$. So comparing with $k$ component, $h(z) = 0$.

Comment: Is the idea to repeat this for $f_y$ and $f_z$, because I notice that $\frac{df}{fx}$ of $f(x,y,z)$ will give the i component, but also half of the j component.

Comment: What do you get for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$?

Comment: $\frac{df}{dx} = 2xcos(y)-2z^3+3y+y^2e^z$, thats if I take the partial with respect to x

Comment: that's wrong. Partial derivative of $(3y+y^2e^z)$ wrt $x$ is zero.

Comment: When we do the same for the f_x, taking the integral of the j component we obtain $3y+2y^2e^z-yx^2sin(y) + \int g(x,z)$, taking j component $g(x,z) = 3-x^2sin(y)$ and then integrating we get $3y+2y^2e^z-yx^2sin(y) + 3x-\{frac{x^3}{3} cos(y)$, checking k $h(z) = 0$ so we have $3y+2y^2e^z-yx^2sin(y) + 3x-\{frac{x^3}{3} cos(y)$ then taking the partial with respect to y $\frac{df}{dy}$ we obtain  $y+4ye^z-yx^2sin(y)$ which is not right, any ideas please? It's because when taking the derivative of $2y^2$ end up in $4y$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123589/discussion-between-math-lover-and-mathemagics).